# Custom shadows in roboelectric 2?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

As per the official guide for Roboelectric 1.X (at http://pivotal.github.io/robolectric/customizing.html), the way to use your own shadow class is to create your own test runner and override the appropriate method OR by using #Roboelectric.bindShadowClass (see below).

However, things have changed for 2.X and I can't seem to find the new way to do this.
Anyone know how to use a custom shadow class without changing the

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
public CustomTestRunner(Class testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
}

@Override public void beforeTest(Method method) {
    Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowBitmapFactory.class);
    Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowDrawable.class);
    Robolectric.bindShadowClass(ShadowGeocoder.class);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new [Robolectric 2.0 Config](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/annotation/Config.html) annotation type to bind custom Shadow classes.

For example you annotate a test method like this:

> @Config( shadows = { MyShadow.class, MyOtherShadow.class } ) 
>    public void testSomething { 
>   ...
>   }

Best Regards,
Seb

Comment: Could you provide a sample project which works? I am able to run shadow imageView but I cannot run the shadow customised classes. Here is my code: https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/RobolectricSample/tree/roboMockitoTutorial